# iOS Universal Links in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I can't seem to get iOS universal links on my Flutter app working. Here are the steps I have taken to setup universal links:

- Installed flutter [uni_links package](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links)
- Uploaded the following apple-app-site-association (with actual values for Team ID & bundle identifier):

  ```
  {
    "applinks": {
     "details": [
          { 
              "appID": "xxxxxxx.com.bundleIdentifier", 
              "paths": [ "*" ], 
              "appIDs": ["xxxxxxx.com.bundleIdentifier"], 
              "components": [ 
                  { "/": "*" } 
              ] 
          }
     ]
  }}
  ```
- Validated apple-app-site-association file via https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ (worth noting that I was not able to validate with Apple's appsearch-validation-tool - received error: "Could not extract required information for Universal Links.")
- Added the associated domain in my project capabilities:
  [screenshot from xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqQM5.png)

Opening with `/usr/bin/xcrun simctl openurl` or clicking on the url on my mobile device (tried from notes app) still opens the url in safari instead of opening the app.

What could I be missing?

Comment: The server you’re using is HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @Shahar HTTPS, and confirmed content-type json

Comment: Add [`mode=developer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains) to your project capabilities to bypass apples CDN. You can also generate a sysdiagnose on your device to get the log file https://www.wwt.com/article/using-sysdiagnose-on-ios-to-troubleshoot-universal-links

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the tip! I added `?mode=developer` to my project capabilities and ran the analytics according to the article. My app is not even showing up in the `swcutil_show.txt` so I'm guessing that means the app isn't even looking for the AASA file? Really dumbfounded as to what I could be missing.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing to check is if the associated domain is actually getting rolled into the build. This setting is in Xcode under Runner => Build Phases => Copy Bundle Resources. Hit the "+" button and add the .entitlements if it is missing. [screenshot of xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMMnx.png)

(I don't remember where I came across this suggestion, whether stack overflow or a github issue, but will add it if I come across it again/remember it).

Comment: It would be worth noting the source of this info; I have not been able to find any reference to this around.

Comment: This worked for me -- didn't see it documented anywhere either

Answer (score 1):

The device reads the AASA file only when the app’s version changes, try to change the version / use another device (/simulator of another device).

Comment: Tried to increment the version, deleted and reinstalled app, still didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Your apple-app-site-association will be hosted will be root or .wellknown path

your content will be look like below,

```
{
  "applinks": {
  "apps": [],
  "details": [
        { 
            "appID": "xxxxxxx.com.bundleIdentifier", 
            "paths": [ "*" ] 
        },
        {
            "appID": ["xxxxxxx.com.bundleIdentifier"], 
            "paths": [ "*" ]
        } 
   ]
}}
```

Your file will be accessible and visible like below
https://google.com/apple-app-site-association 
https://example-your-domain.com/apple-app-site-association

Your **`apple-app-site-association`** file doesn't contains any extension.
Set content type based on your config => https://gist.github.com/anhar/6d50c023f442fb2437e1#-modifying-the-content-type-of-the-apple-app-site-association-file

---

**Add your domains under Associated Domains in Signing & Capabilities**

[image]

Comment: Yes my apple-app-site-association is hosted at /.well-known/apple-app-site-association. I can actually see my AASA when querying here: https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/. So I feel like that part must be correct

Comment: @Nour Same problem here. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @MatthewTrent did you added your domains under Associated Domains in Signing & Capabilities

Comment: @RamprasathSelvam Mine just updated now and works, turns out it just took a while even tho Apple had already cached it for it to update :)