# Universal link data not working on Flutter iOS release

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

I am building a feature where users who don't have my app but want to add someone to their friends list can follow a Firebase dynamic link to install the app and sign up. Once the user signs up, data is pulled from that dynamic link to start the new user's account with that existing person in their friends list. It works as exactly expected on Android. I can use the [firebase_dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) package to accomplish this with `FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink()`.

However, when I first tried to do this on iOS, the link data was null and I couldn't get the query parameters I needed. A lot of other people had an issue with this too and they recommended the [app_links](https://pub.dev/packages/app_links) package. After tinkering with my code a bit, I was able to get it working in my development environment using `AppLinks().getInitialAppLink()`. I figured that I had solved the issue and I was ready to release so I made an archive and released it to the App Store. When I tested the new feature in production, it wasn't working on iOS again but it works on Android.

Is there something wrong with my iOS configuration? Here's all the relevant info I have so far:

My Info.plist file contains the following:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>Bundle ID</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.my.bundle</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
<array>
    <string>https://app.mydomain.com/</string>
    <string>https://app.mydomain.com/connect</string>
</array>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
</array>
```

My associated domains in my XCode project looks like this:
[image: XCode screenshot]

I have the "Copy Bundle Resources" under Build Phases set like this and added the entitlements that someone said I needed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69061908/9265255):

[image: Build Phases]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hercheck: Did you ever end up finding a solution? I have the same problem.